# SendKeys não funciona com palavra acentuada no VBA - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, script

Estou desenvolvendo um *script* em VBA, no Excel.
Esse código preencherá um outro programa, usando os dados coletados nas células.
Mas as células que contêm alguma palavra que possua acentos, não estão funcionando.

Eu estou usando o `Application.SendKeys` como, no trecho abaixo, para preencher o outro programa

```
Sub teste()
   '(...)
    For i=2 to ultimaLinha
        'parte que simula o clique no mouse
        Application.SendKeys (Plan2.Cells(i,"D").Value)
        'restante do código
    Next
    '(...)
End Sub
```

Se nessa célula (i,"D") tiver uma palavra que não contenha acentuação, vai tudo muito bem.
Mas se possuir acento, ele não é "digitado"

Por exemplo: se na célula estiver escrito 'José Mauricio', vai ser digitado só **Jos Mauricio**
E é necessário que seja enviada exatamente como está contido na célula, pois o programa vai receber essa informação em uma *listbox* e, por causa da validação de dados que a *listbox* tem, ela não aceitaria se fosse digitado **Jose Mauricio** no lugar de **José Mauricio**, porque não existe na lista

Como eu faria para que os acentos sejam enviados?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui solucionar o problema usando apenas `SendKeys` (sem o `Application.`)

Mas por algum motivo, tive que adicionar um tempo de espera, antes da linha do código que continha ele.

Mas o `SendKeys`, apesar de escrever as palavras com acentuação, como eu estava precisando, ele pula os caracteres que são parênteses "*(*" e "*)*".

Como eu sei que não haverá, nessa lista que recebe as informações, itens iguais, que possuam parênteses à sua direita e após esse caractere, tenham algum dado diferente, tive que localizar a posição desse caractere especial e mandar enviar apenas o que contém até a posição imediatamente anterior a ele, na palavra

O código final ficou assim:

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub teste()

   '(...)

    For i = 2 To ultimaLinha

        'parte que simula o clique no mouse

        indice = InStr(1, Plan2.Cells(i, "D").Value, Chr(40)) 'procura por ( - Chr(40)
        indice2 = InStr(1, Plan2.Cells(i, "D").Value, Chr(34)) 'procura por " - (Chr(34)

        Sleep (500)

        palavra = ""

        If indice > 0 Then
            For j = 1 To (indice - 1)
                palavra = palavra & Mid(Plan2.Cells(i, "D").Value, j, 1)
            Next
            SendKeys (palavra)
        End If
        If indice2 > 0 Then
            For k = 1 To (indice2 - 1)
                palavra = palavra & Mid(Plan2.Cells(i, "D").Value, k, 1)
            Next
            SendKeys (palavra)
        End If
        If indice = 0 And indice2 = 0 Then
            SendKeys (Plan2.Cells(i, "D").Value)
        End If

        'restante do código

    Next

    '(...)

End Sub
```